# How to make a CDialog?

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog

I have tried multiple things but the base comes to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <afxwin.h>


main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{

   printf( "\nHello World\n\n" );

   CDialog *dlg = new CDialog();
   dlg->DoModal();

   while (true) {
      Sleep(1); // Sleep is a windows function
   }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

[image: Debug Assertion Failed Message]

What am I missing for this dialog?

I looked up several resources, but everything results in the same error message.

Can someone tell me what am I not seeing?

Comment: You want to display a dialog, okay. But what do you want it to contain? Just some text (use `MessageBox` instead)? Or some kind of form (create a dialog-based project instead)? Something else?

Comment: in the end i want to want to get some information from the dialog. but first i want to get a empty dialog to show up :D

Comment: For getting started, just use the Visual Studio application wizard to create a "dialog-based" application. This will generate the necessary code to create an "empty" dialog. Later you can try to do everything from scratch but for beginners it's recommended to use the wizard.

Answer (score 3):

Using the MFC in a console application requires some initializations.
Without this you will get asserts.

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
        return 8;
    }
```

You must also use a resource that is bound to the CDialog. You may use the appropriate constructors. Or you derive your own dialog from CDialog using the class wizard.

But it doesn't make sense to me to create an MFC console application and use dialogs... Your question may need more details, what you want to do, and why you want to do it in this way.

You may need to read some books or article before you continue this way of programming.

Comment: You don't need to derive from `CDialog`. Were that the case, all explicit constructors would be protected (they're *not*). It is, however, rather limited in the things you can do (because really, you're not doing much of anything except allowing default processing from `CDialog`. The most important parts of this answer are (a) setting up MFC properly, and (b) ensuring the dialog is bound to a resource (as opposed to using the unbound constructor). *Neither* of those are currently in the OPs code, and *both* should be.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Changed my answer.